# How to get the letters of a string after a certain character

Tags: php

I have some code that returns the file type (audio/mp3 or audio/wma etc) The user can download the file and i need to name the file test.mp3 or test.wma as appropriate. so i would like a string that returns the letters after the / 
Thanks

Comment: it's wrong way. You need to collect all types and associate them with extensions. When you will do this, you will understand, why you can't just take part after '/' :)

Comment: So how do i go by creating the file with the right extension?

Comment: The correct mime type for MP3 is `audio/mpeg` btw. So you might need a more explicit mime->extension map.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
if (strpos($mime, '/') !== false)
{
    $type = substr(strstr($mime, '/'), 1);
}
```

Or:

```
$type = preg_replace('~^.+[/](.+)$~', '$1', $mime);
```